# Required to identify day light savings epoch time

Tags: bash, shell, dst

I have a shell script. During daylight saving happening in November, for the time 1:30 a.m. Which repeats itself twice will I be able to differentiate between the two Epoch time?. I want to call a java program during the second Epoch time (second time the 1:30 a.m. is repeating) so I need to identify whether it is the first or the second. How can I identify whether it is a 1st 1:30 a.m. on the 2nd 1:30 a.m.?

Comment: Java offers the industry-leading java.time classes for doing date-time work, including graceful handling of anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST). And Java offers the excellent Executor framework with classes such as `ScheduledExecutorService` to schedule code to run. So I would let a Java app do this work rather than  using a bash shell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (or epoch time) is defined as

> the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 **Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)**, Thursday, 1 January 1970

and since DST changes are not observed in the UTC time, you'll notice **no discontinuities in the epoch time**.

For example, if the first `02:30 +02:00` (before DST) is `1508900000` in epoch, the second `02:30 +01:00` (after DST) will be `1508900000 + 3600 = 1508903600`.

Comment: I had mentioned wrongly that my script is using epoch time. my scripts using the date function which I think Returns the the seconds as per server time zone (ET).

Comment: How to differentiate between these 2 values  seconds?

Comment: Just use "date +%s", it'll give you the datetime in epoch time (in UTC). If you calculate the exact epoch time for the first and second moment, you'll be able to differentiate between because they'll be two different values (3600s apart). Can you tell me the exact date and time of the first moment?

Comment: So it's going to be different epoch "seconds" for first 1.30 & 2nd 1:30 on Nov 5th if I Just use "date +%s" ?? What is TZ fix provided then?

Comment: Yes, it's going to be different. If you set the timezone in your system/environment, the "date" will know how convert the local time to UTC.